# EBICS 3.0 Schema H005 [EBICS_INVALID_XML] XML invalid according to EBICS XML schema

Tags: node.js, xml, banking

I try to implement EBICS 3.0 communication but I can't send correctly my INI request.

I use NodeJS Ebics Client (https://github.com/eCollect/node-ebics-client) 
that I try to edit to use H005 schema but I get [EBICS_INVALID_XML] XML invalid according to EBICS XML schema error when I try to send the request.

There is the generated XML (with fake data of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ebicsUnsecuredRequest xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns="urn:org:ebics:H005" Version="H005" Revision="1">
    <header authenticate="true">
        <static>
            <HostID>EBIXQUAL</HostID>
            <PartnerID>123456789987654321</PartnerID>
            <UserID>123456789987654321</UserID>
            <Product Language="en">Node Ebics Client 0.0.7</Product>
            <OrderDetails>
                <AdminOrderType>INI</AdminOrderType>
            </OrderDetails>
            <SecurityMedium>0000</SecurityMedium>
        </static>
        <mutable />
    </header>
    <body>
        <DataTransfer>   <OrderData>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</OrderData>
        </DataTransfer>
    </body>
</ebicsUnsecuredRequest>
```

For me the structure of the document seems correct. Isn't it ?
What's wrong with this XML document ?

The schema seems to be there https://github.com/openyard/ebics/tree/master/xsd/h005

Is someone have ever try the implementation of the new stantard in nodeJS ?
If yes please give your feedback

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't it working? What is the servers response?

Comment: @seasick Server sends that XML is not correct. technicalCodeSymbol:
 [code ] [EBICS_INVALID_XML] XML invalid according to EBICS XML schema',
  technicalCodeShortText: 'XML invalid according to EBICS XML schema',
  technicalCodeMeaning:
   'XML validation with EBICS schema failed or XML not well-formed',
  businessCode: '000000',
  businessCodeSymbol: 'EBICS_OK',
  businessCodeShortText: 'OK',
  businessCodeMeaning:
   'No technical errors occurred during processing of the EBICS request', [/code]

Comment: The XML looks good to me. You could update the question with code, so others might try to reproduce it

Answer (score 1):

To get it working with EBICS 3.0, ensure that S002 is used within your OrderData, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SignaturePubKeyOrderData xmlns="http://www.ebics.org/S002" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:s001="http://www.ebics.org/S002" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ebics.org/S002 ebics_signature_S002.xsd">
    <SignaturePubKeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <SignatureVersion>A005</SignatureVersion>
    </SignaturePubKeyInfo>
    <PartnerID>XYZ</PartnerID>
    <UserID>ABC</UserID>
</SignaturePubKeyOrderData>
```

Also ensure that your Certificate is correctly created.
E.g.: under WSL (in Windows 10+) or Linux with openssl:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
openssl genrsa -out /mnt/c/Temp/auth.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key /mnt/c/Temp/auth.pem -out /mnt/c/Temp/auth.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in /mnt/c/Temp/auth.csr -signkey  /mnt/c/Temp/auth.pem -out  /mnt/c/Temp/auth.crt
```

Then read in your auth.crt file.
Using BouncyCastle, this can be achieved with (example in C#):

```
 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"c:/Temp/sign.crt");
```